Counting up/shifting right, counting down/shifting left 4164 DRAM addresses using TTL/CMOS
I'm working on a design that uses 4164 (64kb x 1 bit) DRAM with 8 addresses (0-7), and I would like to be able to utilize a TTL/CMOS counter or shift register to make the data output count down/go in reverse via a switch (more on this in a moment). I have had success with using XOR gates (address inputs go to individual XOR inputs, all other XOR inputs are tied to a common line, and then you feed the common line an inverted clock signal), but there is some glitchiness there.
It seems to me that something like a pair of 74HC193 or 74HC194 cascaded would be able to handle this, but I' having some issues. For the 74HC193 you need to have the opposite clock held high (if you want to shift left, you hold the CPU pin high, and vice versa), but I'm having issues cascading the counters and getting them to function properly. The addresses are fed into the inputs and the outputs are either counted up or down. As it stands it passes the address information just fine, but I cannot seem to get it to count down/reverse the data. For this I currently have MR and /PL tied low (0V-5V system).
For switching I'm using a 74HCT4053, where a momentary button press controls two SPDT switches which will switch between clock and high on the CPU pin, and the opposite for the CPD pin (so one button press switches the clock and high signals on each pin per the datasheet), which SHOULD reverse the order, but does not. I'm wondering if there's some additional logic I might be missing. For the clock source I am using address 7, which is the MSB for the 4164 DRAM.
The datasheet for the 74HC193 includes an example of how to cascade two to make an 8-bit counter, but I'm uncertain if I'm incorrect in assuming which one is which (am I giving the count up/down commands to the 193 with the LSB or the MSB, etc.?)

Here is another example with a similar layout, though it uses an outside input signal to control the up/down counting.
Is there a more elegant way of doing this, or am I missing something in the application? Should I be looking at using a 74HC194 instead, and - if so - how would I configure that?

I have no idea what you're trying to do with the DRAM, but to start with, the 4164 is 64 kilobits × 1, and it has a multiplexed address bus for a total of 16 address bits (8 bits row, 8 bits column). Reading, writing and keeping this memory refreshed requires a non-trivial state machine. Can you give us a high-level description of what it is you're trying to accomplish?

@DaveTweed right, it's 64kb x 1 bit (simple typo/omission in the original post), and it uses 8 addresses via RAS and CAS. Apologies if the post wasn't clear - I laid it out as succinctly as I could and provided an example (it's also not the easiest to search for something like this, because of the generic terms involved): what I would like to do is to be able to reverse the data output using counters or shift registers controlling the address lines. I was able to accomplish this with XOR gates as I mentioned, but there is some noise from what I assume is a fair amount of propagation delay.
